# animation query bubbling - how to handle it properly when using slideToggle?

Tags: jquery, animation, toggle, event-bubbling

I need an answer to the following question... I have the problem when I use slideToggle I can't handle it's animation query with .stop(), i can handle it with .stop(true,true) though but it cuts my animation. I want to handle it smoothly without any plugins for example :
I want it to wait till the animation finishes.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you just want the first argument of [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to be `true`, like this:

```
.stop(true)
```

The first argument clears the queue, the second one jumps to the end, if you just want the queue cleared, leave off the last `true` :)

Comment: That doesn't work please try it like this :
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#lol').hover(function(){
      $('#box').stop(true).slideToggle();
  },function(){
    $('#box').stop(true).slideToggle();
  })
});
 </script>
    <style>
        #lol{
            width:50px;
            height:50px;
            background : red;
}
#box {height:200px; width: 200px; background : blue;}
 </style>
<body>
    <div id="lol">

    </div>
    <div id="box">
        
    </div>
It doesn't work I tried it before i asked this question but nice try...
Correct me if I'm wrong 
Thanks

Comment: and yea try rapidly moving over and out of the #box element(red box)

Comment: @vanjadjurdjevic - You need to clear the height to get rid of that behavior with `.css('height','')` you can see a full example here: http://jsfiddle.net/NHsKk/

Comment: @NickCraver Maaaan! This was slowly killing me trying to stop the `slideToggle();` animation with `event.stopPropagation();` the past hours. **So glad I found this!**